# Update IBM WebSphere Application Server Liberty Network Deployment 8.5.5.0 to 8.5.5.1 failed (via Installation Manager)

Tags: websphere, failed-installation, websphere-liberty

Today I tried to update (via Installation Manager)
IBM WebSphere Application Server Liberty Network Deployment 8.5.5.0
to 8.5.5.1

Update failed with message:

Error during "post-install configure" phase:

CRIMA1076E: Error executing the /bin/sh command: status=1. 
For more information, see the agent log file: /home/dsidelnikov/var/ibm/InstallationManager/logs/native/20131112_1734.log

Explanation: The installation operation failed due to an error executing the exec command.An issue has occurred with the package that cannot be resolved by Installation Manager.

User Action: Identify the package that has the issue. Contact IBM Support.

log file contains one message:
/bin/sh: /home/dsidelnikov/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/lib/versions/service.fingerprint: No such file or directory

I checked, file service.fingerprint exists.

Is it known issue?

Comment: This looks like a product issue.  I recommend opening a PMR with IBM as suggested by the user action.

Comment: It might be worth checking that the file is writeable by the user account doing the install.